# Use enum names without prefix in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to use enum name without its prefix?

```
enum class Color { red, blue, green }

data class Shape(val color: Color)

fun main() {
    println(Shape(color = red))
}
```

P.S.

Or maybe it has something like literal types in TypeScript? I don't actually need Enum, the string value would be fine as soon as the Compiler would be able to **check the values at compile time**, like in TypeScript.

```
type Color = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green'

class Shape {
    constructor(public color: Color) {}
}

console.log(new Shape('red')) // Will be validated at compile time
```

Comment: Which prefix do you mean? The class prefix like `Color.red`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an enum without the class prefix if you import it:

```kotlin
import Color.*

enum class Color { Red, Blue, Green }

val color = Red
```

*Note: By convention, [enum names](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names) should start with an uppercase letter.*

**Edit**

First I thought it would be possible to not import the enum when you use it within the same file but in a different class or top-level function, but you still have to import it - to avoid the class prefix.

Comment: Thanks, but the first code in [your examle](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjMwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZW51bSBjbGFzcyBDb2xvciB7IFJlZCwgQmx1ZSwgR3JlZW4gfVxuXG52YWwgY29sb3IgPSBSZWQifQ==) won't compile

Comment: @Alex Craft you are right. Will update my answer